# How to set multiindex column from existing df

Tags: python, pandas

How to set multi index column from existing df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 21, 31],
               'B': [12, 22, 32],
               'C': [13, 23, 33]},
              index=['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'])
```

Expected output

```
          level1        
          level2        
               A   B   C
    ONE       11  12  13
    TWO       21  22  23
    THREE     31  32  33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MultiIndex

```
   df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['level1'],['level2'],df.columns ])
```